# Google translate: Hebrew, why no pronunciation? Why some languages have it and others not?

Tags: pronunciation, russian, hebrew, translation, hungarian

If I put in a word in English and translate it to Arabic, we get Arabic spelling as well an how to pronounce the word. But not for Hebrew -- we only get the word in Hebrew letters. Yiddish also gives us both the word in Hebrew alphabet and the pronunciation.

I did not check every language but so far, Hebrew and Hungarian seem to be the exceptions and I wonder what is special about, for example, Hebrew that makes it this way. I know that the reader is expected to provide vowels, but so what? I would think this would make the pronunciation even more valuable.

In general, what is it about some languages that makes Google translate omit the pronunciation? Could it be as simple as Google has not gotten around to it? I doubt this and I hope someone can explain the characteristics of a language that make pronunciation either hard or unnecessary. The latter case might be, well, some languages are completely phonetic in spelling, but Russian I think is such a language and Google does provide translation.

Comment: This sounds like a question about Google Translate, rather than about learning or teaching languages. If you want to know about the characteristics of Hebrew compared to certain other languages, the question is also off topic here. Linguistics SE seems to accept questions about differences about languages, but you probably need to be specific about what you want to compare. If you want your question to be migrated to Linguistics SE, please let me know.